# matlab-mex-c++: in a for loop, It's slow to assign a non-constant value to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, matlab, for-loop

I tried to use matlab mex (c++) to optimize my matlab program. The problem is that assigning a value (not constant) to an array is very slow. I cannot find the answer myself.

**Background:**

The c++ source code is following:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{ ...

    int row_num = 6000, col_num=4000;
    int total_sim_num=row_num*row_num, total_rate_num=row_num*col_num;

    plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(row_num, row_num, mxSINGLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
    //plhs[0] is the pointer of output matrix, and, indeed, it's an 1-D vector.
    //Matlab code can use it as 2-D matrix.

    float* out_mat = (float*)mxGetData(plhs[0]);
    //later, I want to write the calculated value to matrix: out_mat
```

This is a 3-layer loop, and the output matrix is large: A_OUT=row_num *row_num

The result depends on some input matrics: A_IN=row_num*col_num.

```
for(int u=0; u<row_num; u++)
{
    for(int v=u, vx=0; v<total_sim_num; v+=row_num, vx++)
    {
        for (int i=u, ix=vx; i<total_rate_num; i+=row_num, ix+=row_num)
        {
            float calculated_value = ix/row_num;  //it's fast.
            out_mat[v] = calculated_value;  //It's very slow (~ 10 minutes)
                                            //out_mat[v] -> A_OUT[u][v] 
            out_mat[v] = 2;  //assign constant, it's fast (< 2 seconds)                     
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the comments:

1. Assign a constant to the out_mat is fast.
2. Assign a calculated value to a local variable is fast.
3. Assign a calculated value to out_mat is very slow.

I also tried this:

```
float* testv = new float[total_sim_num];
```

then:

```
testv[v] = calculated_value; //It's very slow too.
```

Can someone share the light that why it's so slow when assigning calculated value to out_mat?
Is it possible to be as fast as assigning a constant to out_mat?

Thanks very much!

Jun

Comment: How do you **know** that the statement in question takes 10 minutes?  What timing tool are you using to measure your MEX code? IIRC, MATLAB's profiler does not work for MEX code. It only measures the total elapsed time the code takes. Also, it's well known that the `single` class for arrays in MATLAB is very buggy.  Do you **have** to use `single`?  Why not use `double` instead?  Use [`mxCreateDoubleMatrix`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatedoublematrix.html) to create your output matrices as MATLAB defaults to using `double` as the data type for creating variables.

Comment: Thanks very much. It's just a observation of the time elapse. I only care how much time it costs when I calling the mex-function. I tried it in VS, all of them are very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing to `out_mat`, you overwrite the same array element (`out_mat[v]`, where `v` is the control variable of the second level `for`-loop) with multiple values different values (sequentially calculated in the third level loop).

So, maybe, when you only assign constants to the array, the compiler optimizes the assignment to the second level loop, and maybe also optimizes away the third level completely.

Are you sure that the code you pasted here is right?

Comment: Thanks very much! I put the codes into vs2013, and found that it's very slow for all those three scenarios. So, maybe,  you are right. The compiler may optimized the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB matrices are stored in column-order. The `mxArray` you are creating is `row_num x row_num` where as it probably should be `row_num x col_num`.

You should then index the `out_mat` array using `i + (j-1)*row_num` to access the `i`th row and `j`th column.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's an implementation of an algorithm. It's good for me to do under this way. Anyway, it can access the data from right index.